# Обработка изменений при нажатии на комплект радиокнопок

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть три радиокнопки. При нажатии на них срабатывает скрипт только когда жмешь на первую. В чем подвох?

```
<script>
$("#qFL1").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "1") alert("Нажата 1"); 
  else if($(this).val() == "2") alert("Нажата 2");
  else alert("Нажата 3"); 
});
</script>

<html>
  <input type="radio" name="qFL1" id="qFL1" value="1">;
  <input type="radio" name="qFL1" id="qFL1" value="2">;
  <input type="radio" name="qFL1" id="qFL1" value="3">;
</html>
```

Comment: Потому что id должен быть уникальным. Иначе выбирается первый встреченный элемент.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что id должен быть уникальным.
Поменяйте id на класс:

```js
$(".qFL1").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "1") alert("Нажата 1"); 
  else if($(this).val() == "2") alert("Нажата 2");
  else alert("Нажата 3"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="qFL1" class="qFL1" value="1">;
<input type="radio" name="qFL1" class="qFL1" value="2">;
<input type="radio" name="qFL1" class="qFL1" value="3">;
```

То же самое без jquery:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("qFL1")).forEach(element => 
  element.addEventListener('click', e => 
    alert(`Нажата ${e.target.value}`)
  )
);
```

```html
1<input type="radio" name="qFL1" class="qFL1" value="1">;
2<input type="radio" name="qFL1" class="qFL1" value="2">;
3<input type="radio" name="qFL1" class="qFL1" value="3">;
```

Comment: Можно по `name` CSS селектор сделать.

Comment: @Alex78191 можно вообще без селектора

Comment: В смысле? Через `onclick`?

Comment: легче `alert("Нажата " + $(this).val());`

Comment: `querySelectorAll` рулит же

Comment: @Alex78191 В целом я согласен, но работает он в разы медленее

Answer (score 2):

Может, банальнее?

```js
$("#qFL1").change(function(){alert("Нажата 1");});
$("#qFL2").change(function(){alert("Нажата 2"); });
$("#qFL3").change(function(){alert("Нажата 3"); });
```

```html
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="radio" name="qFL1" id="qFL1" value="1">;
  <input type="radio" name="qFL1" id="qFL2" value="2">;
  <input type="radio" name="qFL1" id="qFL3" value="3">;
</html>
```

Comment: тогда можно все три выбрать. Нужно только одну. Оп стоп, так я еще не делал)))

Comment: @VitVlad Отнюдь